# Integrate bootsrap carousel with multiple items in angular 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use bootsrapt carousel with multiple items as it's demonstrated in this [Bootply code](http://www.bootply.com/117282) but it doesn't work with angular 2.

I integrated this carousel in my angular 2 project [Plunkr code](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5lDxrDUFlNQQZimUhk9) 
These are the jquery , css and html codes I'm using to get a mutiple item carousel. H

```js
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular2Restful</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Agile plant disease monitoring">
  <meta name="author" content="APDM">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="col-lg-8 text-center"><h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 ">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--   <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/chartjs-plugin-annotation/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
 -->  <script type="text/javascript" onload>
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to make it work with angular 2? There is an animation problem.
Note: Even if it looks like it works here in the code snippet, I wish you take a look at the link and click on the right button. I'm getting the same effect in in my local project and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have used **ng bootstrap** and created one carousal with mat card u can get it from below github path
[Github-angular-carousal](https://github.com/lijoos/angular-carousal)

Please see the hosted sample [here](https://angular-carousal.firebaseapp.com/)

[image]